# Need to pull data from website after every 5 seconds using Vba

Tags: windows-7, windows, vba

I need to pull data from www.dsebd.org after ever 5 seconds. this Vba code pull data but does not run automatically. Please help me.

```
Sub ButtonCode()

     ' execute macros
    Call GetCotton
     ' submit macro to run again in 5 sec
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "ButtonCode"

End Sub

Sub GetCotton()

        Dim xml    As Object
    Dim html   As Object
    Dim elemcollection As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim t As Long, r As Long, c As Long, ActRw As Long
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", "http://www.dsebd.org/dseX_share.php", False
        .send
    End With
    result = xml.responseText
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = result
    Set elemcollection = html.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For t = 0 To elemcollection.Length - 1
        For r = 0 To elemcollection(t).Rows.Length - 1
            For c = 0 To elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + r + 1, c + 1) = elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
        ActRw = ActRw + elemcollection(t).Rows.Length + 1
    Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Yes. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + r + 1, c + 1) = elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText This line is in error.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: THE IS IN THIS LINE. WHEN I RUN THE MACRO, A DEBUGGING ERROR SHOWS IN THIS LINE WITH YELLOW COLOR. PLEASE HELP ME. I AM IN DYING NEED. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + r + 1, c + 1) = elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText

Comment: Writing in capitals won't help you. You still don't seem to understand me. What is the error message? Does it say "Error code 0111015" or does it say "Debug issue"? Is there any error message? I ran your code with no issue.

Comment: Dear Dave, I feel sorry first. The error message is " Run-time error'1004': Application defined or object-defined error." Now if I put click on debug button, this line (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + r + 1, c + 1) = elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText) is marked with yellow color. Please help me.

Comment: Can you try this in a new Excel workbook please

Comment: Dear dave, thanks for spending your valuable time on a stupid like me. But sorry to say that I have tried with a new file having extension .xlsb . This time there is no error message but a message shows that (can not run the macro). How can I be successful?

Comment: Does it not work saved as xlsm ?

Comment: Dear Dave, same result for xlsm. Can you please do me a favour? If possible please send me a soft copy of the file so that I can extract data from website after every 05 seconds. I need the data very much.

Comment: Dear Dave, I am waiting for your kind reply.

Comment: I sent you the file . I. Can't help any more

Comment: Thanks Dave, I am so much grateful that you have taken so much pain for me. But I think it is my misfortune that I can run your file. When I run the macro, It says out of memory. What can I do now?......

Comment: Upgrade your RAM

Comment: Thanks Dave. It is working on my Laptop. But I can not check the real data as the market is closed now. I thank you again for your generous help. I will let you know my progress.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what the error message is, or where it occurs. I suspect it can't find the code in question. So, change

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "ButtonCode"
```

to

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "thisworkbook.ButtonCode"
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Even after the proposed correction I have the same debug prolem. The prblem is in " ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + r + 1, c + 1) = elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText"